# Highcharts Solid Gauge Pane

Tags: c#, highcharts

I was wondering whether the pane inside the solid gauge was a list or an object. I see in the notes that it is a simple object

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/pane

but the following jsfiddle seems to refer to a chart with multiple panes, suggesting the pane can take an array

```
jsfiddleCode
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-vu-meter

Making this even more complex, I am using the .net version of Highcharts (v7.2.0), and can add a new Pane, but cannot add a new List to the chart

**working C# code**

[image]

**Does not work**

[image]

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The pan could be an object or array of objects - it depends if you want to create a chart with multiple series/axis/panes, like it is done in the example which you have shared or just a single one, like here: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-speedometer/

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thanks for the reply - The problem is that I cannot seem to define an array of panes within the .net wrapper version (at least not as a list<pane>). I can only specify a single pane. At the end of the day, I would like to have a chart with multiple panes, where I can assign a Y-axis to each pane.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem I was facing using a combination of TickLength and Offset for my individual y axes (on the single pane), but I think this would have been easier if I had multiple panes.